# Subscripted arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

Is it possible to create a subscripted array in C which uses another array as its indexes.  I went through a link: [IDL — Using Arrays as Subscripts](http://northstar-www.dartmouth.edu/doc/idl/html_6.2/Using_Arrays_as_Subscripts.html)

Arrays can be used as subscripts to other arrays. Each element in the subscript array selects an element in the subscripted array.

For another example, consider the statements:

```
A = [6, 5, 1, 8, 4, 3]  
B = [0, 2, 4, 1]  
C = A[B]  
PRINT, C
```

This produces the following output:

```
6       1       4       5
```

Is the above possible in C programming.

Comment: Yes; C is clean and orthogonal like that (though you'd need to choose which subscript of `B` you wanted to use to index `A`; `A[B[3]]` is OK, but `A[B]` is not).  Subscript expressions can be arbitrarily complex.  The only bad news is that you get no subscript checking.  If your complex expression generates an index that it out of bounds, the compiler won't tell you — your program might appear to work but get indeterminate behaviour, or it might crash uncontrollably, or you might corrupt important data, or … well, don't do it; make sure your array subscripts are within bounds, always.

Comment: Your code would be more convincing if it was compilable C.  What you show is at best a pseudo-code.  Avoid that on SO.

Comment: However, although C subscripts can be arbitrarily complex, there are essentially no built-in facilities for manipulating arrays as a whole.  The IDL notation you use does not translate directly.  You can't assign a whole array.  You can't do array selection in a single operation as shown.  You'd have to write the loop yourself: `for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]); i++) C[i] = A[B[i]];` — which gives you immense control but at the cost of having to do the work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Arrays can be used as subscripts to other arrays. Each element in the subscript array selects an element in the subscripted array.

Syntactically this is not directly possible in C. You've to use a loop to achieve this.

```
int a[] = {6, 5, 1, 8, 4, 3};
int b[] = {0, 2, 4, 1};
for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0])); ++i)
    printf("%d\n", a[b[i]]);
```

If you really want it to look that neat, then wrap it in a function and you should be alright:

```
// returns the no. of elements printed
// returns -1 when index is out of bounds
int print_array(int *a, int *b, size_t na, size_t nb)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nb; ++i)
    {
        int const index = b[i];
        if (index >= na)
            return -1;
        print("%d\n", a[index]);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: I'd do `i < sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]))`, but apart from that, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

The array index operator in C can only take integer arguments. This is because the compiler will expand the operation, like `A[0]`, into a basic addition and dereference. As such, you can't pass an array as the operand to extract several indices from the original array.

Remember that `A[0]` is the same as `*A`, and `A[1]` is the same as `*(A + 1)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ofcourse it is:

```
int a[6] = { 6, 5, 1, 8, 4, 3 };
int b[4] = { 0, 2, 4, 1 };

printf("\na[b[0]]=%d", a[b[0]]);
printf("\na[b[1]]=%d", a[b[1]]);
printf("\na[b[2]]=%d", a[b[2]]);
printf("\na[b[3]]=%d", a[b[3]]);
```

output:

> `a[b[0]]=6
>   a[b[1]]=1
>   a[b[2]]=4
>   a[b[3]]=5`

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible!
In C, the array operator [x] is just a shorthand for a pointer addition.
So a[x] is the same as (a+x)* 
This means the only valid arguments for the array operator are Integers.